# lookup key by key in Java map or set

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

In most languages, including Java, there is an API something like `java.util.Map` which is designed to make it easy to loop up a value, given the key that maps to it.  But there is not always a convenient way to look up the key, given the key (I'm pretty sure Python makes it hard, C++ makes it easy (just ask for an iterator), this question is about Java, which I suspect as as bad as Python).  At first this may sound dumb: why would you need to look up a key you already have?  But consider something like this (example below uses `Set` instead of `Map`, but same idea):

```
TreeSet<String> dictionary = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
dictionary.add("Monday"); // populate dictionary
String word = "MONDAY"; // user input, or something
if(dictionary.contains(word)) System.out.println(word + " already in dictionary");
```

The above code snippet will print `MONDAY already in dictionary`.  This is of course wrong, because "MONDAY" is not in the dictionary; rather, "Monday" is.  How can we make the message more accurate?  In this case, we can make a help function that take advantage of the fact that a `TreeSet` is a `NavigableSet`  (Actually a similar trick works for `SortedSet`, though it's a bit less convenient.):

```
String lookup(NavigableSet<String> set, String key) {
    assert set.contains(key) : key + " not in set";
    return set.floor(key);
}
```

Now we can fix the last line of the previous code snippet:

```
if(dictionary.contains(word)) System.out.println(lookup(word) + " already in dictionary");
```

Which will print the correct thing.  But now let's try an example with a hash set:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
/** Maintains a set of strings; useful as a replacement for String.intern() */
class StringInterner {
    private final HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    /** use this instead of String.intern() */
    String intern(String s) {
         if(!set.contains(s)) {
             s.add(s);
             return s;
         }
         for(String str : set) // linear scan!!
             if(str.equals(s)) return str;
         throw new AssertionError("something went very wrong");
    }
}
```

The code above resorts to a linear scan to find something that it already knows is there.  Note that `HashSet` could easily give us what we're looking for, because it needs to be able to do this just to implement `contains()`.  But there's no API for it, so we can't even ask the question.  (Actually, `HashMap` has an internal method called `getNode` which is pretty much what we want, but it is internal.)  An easy workaround in this case is to use a map instead of a set: instead of `set.add(s)` we could instead use `map.put(s,s)`.  But what if we're already using a map, because we already have data we want to associate with our key?  Then we can either use two maps, and carefully keep them in sync, or else store a tuple of size 2 as the "value" in our map, where the first item in the tuple is simply the map key.  Both of these solutions seem needlessly awkward.

Is there a better way?

Comment: use hashmap... iterate over EntrySet.

Comment: Sure, you can always do a linear scan.  But the nice thing about hash maps is that they usually have fast lookup; it seems a pity to lose that and instead use a brute force scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way?

No, there isn't.

For HashMaps, it doesn't matter, because your "two equivalent keys" argument doesn't make sense for `HashMap`.  The two keys will always have to be `equals`, which as far as Java is concerned, means they should be substitutable in every way.

Comment: Not quite every way.  Sometimes you care about object identity (that is, sometimes you care if things are `==`, not merely `equals()`).  For instance, a proper implementation of `String.intern()` has to respect object identity.  (To see why, consider the purpose of interning a String: you typically want logic something like "if I've seen a string like this before, discard this one and use the one from before".  This lets you save memory because you avoid storing multiple equal strings.)

Comment: Yes.  And in the case of Interner-like things, the best you can do is `Map<Foo, Foo>`.  There is nothing better, sorry if you were hoping for something more.  The reason there's nothing better is because practically nobody needs anything better, and this doesn't even make sense for less standard `Map` implementations, e.g. ones that don't even keep the identity of their keys.

Comment: Sigh.  Unfortunate.  Seems like a hole in the API that would be nice to fill in one day.

Comment: Side note: the contract for `equals()` is explicitly stated in the java docs.  There is no requirement that `equals()` capture everything you might care about, and indeed there are sometimes good reasons not to (pretty rare I admit, but happens).  I probably care a lot whether I have an ArrayList or a LinkedList (e.g., if I'm considering whether to do binary search or not), but according to the List contract, any two lists with the same elements in the same order must be considered equal().

Comment: In that situation, you should use `Collections.binarySearch`, which always does the right thing.  I don't think this is a hole in need of filling.

Comment: Right, I meant that more as example where two objects might be equals() but not equivalent.  To be more explicit: you may have a `Set<ArrayList>`, and you might want to perform a lookup in that set using a linked list, and get the matching array list back out.

Comment: I finally looked at your StackOverflow profile; didn't realize you were on core-libs-dev ... I guess I'll have to take your "No there isn't" as likely definitive instead of hoping that perhaps there's a trick you haven't thought of.

Comment: Note that you could create a case insensitive `HashMap`/`HashSet` by using a special key type (might be a wrapper around the string) with appropriate `hashCode`/`equals` implementations, which will introduce right the problem of the question; you can not query a `Set` for the string originally used to create the key. But it’s worth noting that since Java 2, the reference implementation (nowadays OpenJDK and all implementations built atop it) implements `HashSet` as a wrapper around a `HashMap`. So using a `HashMap` to solve this issue does not change the performance characteristics.